# Why am I getting NSUnkownKeyException?

Tags: ios, swift

I have looked at the answers of this question here and none of them seem to fix the problem I am having, also most other answers are not for swift but  i tried the ones I understood.

All of the class names match, the outlets have the right names and there are no outlets that aren't defined... no little yellow triangle. (links to images below, site wont let me put more than 2)

[Shows class names in inspector and file are the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPv2q.png)

[Shows outlet names in file and inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEPJN.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reasonthis-class-is-not-key-valu)

Answer (score 0):

As the screenshot clearly shows, the property `MyInputText` does not bind to anything. Did you connect the `UITextField` in the `UIStoryBoard` to the related property in the code?

Here a screenshot showing a proper binding between a property and the XIB object.

Here a screenshot showing a proper binding between a property and the XIB object.

[image: Connections Inspector]

Comment: With ctrl drag right? Im pretty sure it is, in my HomeViewController, when I mouse over the little grey circle next to MyInputText it highlights the UITextField blue

Comment: Yes exactly, check this on the right panel selection the xib, the UIStoryboard and the the UITextField. At that point, select `Show Connections Inspector` and check if in `Referencing Outlets` you see the binding. I have update the post with a picture showing this.